# Chef Windows - Failing in require block

Tags: chef-infra

I am installing aws-sdk gem  in the my chef recipe on windows like this

```
chef_gem 'aws-sdk'
require 'aws-sdk'
```

The chef gem 'aws-sdk' gets installed successfully but it throws a error on

```
require 'aws-sdk'
```

The error is  `LoadError  - cannot load such file --- aws-sdk`. What I am doing .wrong here. Here is the full output from chef

```
[2015-01-18T05:13:38+00:00] INFO: Running start handlers
[2015-01-18T05:13:38+00:00] INFO: Start handlers complete.
[2015-01-18T05:13:38+00:00] WARN: found a directory attributes in the cookbook path, but it contains no cookbook files. skipping.
[2015-01-18T05:13:38+00:00] WARN: found a directory definitions in the cookbook path, but it contains no cookbook files. skipping.
[2015-01-18T05:13:38+00:00] WARN: found a directory files in the cookbook path, but it contains no cookbook files. skipping.
[2015-01-18T05:13:39+00:00] INFO: Processing chef_gem[aws-sdk] action install (set_up_machine::default line 31)

================================================================================
Recipe Compile Error in C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\wincookbook\set_up_machine\recipes\default.rb
================================================================================

    LoadError
    ---------
    cannot load such file -- aws-sdk

    Cookbook Trace:
    ---------------
      C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
      C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
      C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\wincookbook\set_up_machine\recipes\default.rb:31:in `from_file'
      C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/mixin/from_file.rb:30:in `instance_eval'
      C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/mixin/from_file.rb:30:in `from_file'
      C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/cookbook_version.rb:245:in `load_recipe'
      C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/run_context.rb:169:in `load_recipe'
      C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:140:in `block in compile_recipes'
      C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:138:in `each'
      C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:138:in `compile_recipes'
      C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:75:in `compile'
      C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/run_context.rb:92:in `load'
      C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/policy_builder/expand_node_object.rb:73:in `setup_run_context'
      C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/client.rb:235:in `setup_run_context'
      C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/client.rb:397:in `run'
      C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application.rb:243:in `run_with_graceful_exit_option'
      C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application.rb:220:in `block in run_chef_client'
      C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/local_mode.rb:38:in `with_server_connectivity'
      C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application.rb:201:in `run_chef_client'
      C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:245:in `block in interval_run_chef_client'
      C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:234:in `loop'
      C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:234:in `interval_run_chef_client'
      C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:224:in `run_application'
      C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application.rb:58:in `run'
      C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/bin/chef-solo:25:in `<top (required)>'
      C:/opscode/chef/bin/chef-solo:52:in `load'
      C:/opscode/chef/bin/chef-solo:52:in `<main>'

    Relevant File Content:
    ----------------------
    C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:

     47:      end
     48:  
     49:      # If there are no unresolved deps, then we can use just try
     50:      # normal require handle loading a gem from the rescue below.
     51:  
     52:      if Gem::Specification.unresolved_deps.empty? then
     53:        RUBYGEMS_ACTIVATION_MONITOR.exit
     54>>       return gem_original_require(path)
     55:      end
     56:  
     57:      # If +path+ is for a gem that has already been loaded, don't
     58:      # bother trying to find it in an unresolved gem, just go straight
     59:      # to normal require.
     60:      #--
     61:      # TODO request access to the C implementation of this to speed up RubyGems
     62:  
     63:      spec = Gem::Specification.stubs.find { |s|
```

Comment: Please include the full output from chef-client.

Comment: I have added the full output from chef-client

Comment: There is a lot of stuff above that, please include _all_ the output.

Comment: There was not much output above. Anyways I have included what was there.

Comment: Just to add when I do  "gem list"  , it shows me aws-sdk installed.

Comment: If you use `C:/opscode/chef/embedded/bin/irb` does it let you import the lib? Depending on the version you may need `'aws-sdk-v1'` instead.

Comment: No I am not able to import the lib in C:/opscode/chef/embedded/bin/irb . Also tried using  'aws-sdk-v1' in chef. Still giving me error.  However when I use C:/Ruby21/bin/irb  , I am able to load 'aws-sdk' .

Answer (score 0):

You're out of luck here because of conflicting ruby on your system.

Your Ruby 2.1 installation has probably set some envrionment variables (like `GEM_PATH`) pointing to your 2.1 install, so when chef run and calls it's own `gem install` the destination for the gem is overriden, but when you require it from the recipe you're in the chef embedded ruby context and it's own path, that's why it can't find it, same for the irb test.

For this kind of situation I tend to have a wrapper `.cmd` which empty the environment and set only the env vars needed (PATH, SSL_CERT_FILE, USERNAME, etc.)

It's a little fail and retry method sometimes to determine which ENV var is needed but on the end you're sure of what you use.